# Can receive but cannot make outgoing calls on an iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, iphone, phone.app

My iPhone 5s which I bought a year ago shows "Call Failed" whenever I hit "send", it doesn't matter which number I'm dialing. I can get incoming calls, FaceTime calls, messages, and apps are working fine. I placed my SIM in another device and mananged to make calls, and I tried putting another SIM in my iPhone, and once again got the instant "Call Failed" message.

Is this more likely to be a software problem or hardware? How can this be addressed?

Comment: Have you tried turning the iPhone off/on to see if that clears things up and if that didn't help have your tried a hard reset?

Comment: Did you call your provider to tell them you were swapping phones/SIMs around at random? - most phones lock down if one doesn't recognise the other.

Answer (score 3):

This happened in my iPhone 4S since one of iOS 7 updates, sent many messages on Apple's contact form, no answer and no fix to date with the latest iOS 8.3, I temporary fix it by dialing *#31#.

It shows a message "Setting Interrogation Succeeded, Calling Line ID Restriction Disabled" and then can call normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am using IPhone 6 and your solution helped me a lot. But what does *#31# really do ?

Comment: *#31# it really works I did it and then calls will be done normally

Comment: @KannanMohan, the code is for checking the status of your Caller ID blocking setting. Why it "clears the pipes" for making outgoing calls is beyond me, but it worked. Here's some more phone status codes: http://www.iphonetricks.org/17-secret-iphone-interrogation-codes/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning the "Cellular data" off then on again?

Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data (toggle)

Answer (score -3):

for iphone 5 5s just dial *#31#

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Comment: The code `*#31#` appears to be related to blocking and unblocking [Caller ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID). The code is country and sometimes network provider specific.